# Error Creating account: failed to send transaction: Transaction simulation failed: Attempt to debit an account but found no record of a prior credit

Tags: web3.js, account

I am creating accounts for my application using custodial wallets while creating account I am getting above error.

```
import {
  Connection,
  Keypair,
  LAMPORTS_PER_SOL,
  SystemProgram,
  Transaction,
  VersionedTransaction,
} from "@solana/web3.js";

const generateKeyPair = async () => {
  try {
    const connection = new Connection(
      RPC_DEVNET_URL_FROM_ALCHEMY,
    );

    const payer = Keypair.generate();
    console.log("Payer:", payer.publicKey.toBase58());

    const keypair = Keypair.generate();
    console.log("New Account:", keypair.publicKey.toBase58());

    await connection.requestAirdrop(payer.publicKey, 5000 * LAMPORTS_PER_SOL);
    waitForAirdropConfirmation(connection, payer.publicKey);
    const lamports = await connection.getMinimumBalanceForRentExemption(0);

    const createAccountIx = SystemProgram.createAccount({
      fromPubkey: payer.publicKey,
      newAccountPubkey: keypair.publicKey,
      lamports,
      space: 0,
      programId: SystemProgram.programId,
    });

    const recentBlockhash = await connection.getLatestBlockhash();

    const transaction = new Transaction({
      recentBlockhash: recentBlockhash.blockhash,
      feePayer: payer.publicKey,
    });

    transaction.add(createAccountIx);

    transaction.sign(payer, keypair);

    console.log("Transaction after signing:", transaction);

    await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 6000)); 
    const signature = await connection.sendTransaction(transaction, [payer, keypair]);

    console.log("Transaction completed. Signature:", signature);
  } catch (error) {
    console.error("Error:", error);
  }
};

const waitForAirdropConfirmation = async (connection, publicKey) => {
  while (true) {
    const balance = await connection.getBalance(publicKey);
    if (balance > 0) {
      console.log(`Airdrop confirmed for ${publicKey.toBase58()}`);
      break;
    }
    await sleep(5000); // Check balance every 5 seconds
  }
};

const sleep = ms => {
  return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));
};

generateKeyPair();
```

Have also tried following code :

```
import {
  Connection,
  Keypair,
  LAMPORTS_PER_SOL,
  SystemProgram,
  TransactionMessage,
  VersionedTransaction,
} from "@solana/web3.js";

const generateKeyPair = async () => {
  try {
    const connection = new Connection(
      RPC_URL_FROM_ALCHEMY_OF_DEVNET,
    );

    const payer = Keypair.generate();
    console.log(payer);
    const keypair = Keypair.generate();
    const space = 0;
    await connection.requestAirdrop(payer.publicKey, 5000 * LAMPORTS_PER_SOL);
    await connection.requestAirdrop(keypair.publicKey, 3000 * LAMPORTS_PER_SOL);
    const lamports = await connection.getMinimumBalanceForRentExemption(space);
    console.log(payer.publicKey);
    console.log(keypair.publicKey);

    const createAccountIx = SystemProgram.createAccount({
      fromPubkey: payer.publicKey,
      newAccountPubkey: keypair.publicKey,
      lamports,
      space,
      programId: SystemProgram.programId,
    });

    let recentBlockhash = await connection.getLatestBlockhash().then(res => res.blockhash);

    const message = new TransactionMessage({
      payerKey: payer.publicKey,
      recentBlockhash,
      instructions: [createAccountIx],
    }).compileToV0Message();

    const tx = new VersionedTransaction(message);

    tx.sign([payer, keypair]);

    console.log("tx after signing:", tx);
    const sig = await connection.sendTransaction(tx);
    console.log("Transaction completed.");
    // const sig = await connection.sendTransaction(tx);
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
};

generateKeyPair();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are requesting 5000 Sol, which is far above the rate limit. You can ask for max 2 Sol a day. To be safer, request 1 Sol and check if it is working.

Comment: Thanks for the solution it is working now with little tweak for confirming the transaction.

```
await connection.confirmTransaction({ signature: airdropSignature });
```